# Many view controllers - performance issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have an IOS app that lets user swipe through weeks of notes. Each week is a UIViewController - the swiping and switching between the view controllers are handled by a UIPageViewController.

On startup all the view controllers are initialised with their data.

When the user swipes I grap a view controller like this:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let currentPageViewController = viewController as? SinglePageViewController {
      let currentIndex = currentPageViewController.index
      return self.weeks[currentIndex - 1]
    }
    return nil
  }
```

The app work flawless, until a use has many weeks, and thereby many view controllers. Startup time start to become an issue - and this will of cause only get worse as the weeks go on.

I've played around with initialising the each view controller when the user swipes. Like this:

```
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let currentPageViewController = viewController as? SinglePageViewController {
          let currentIndex = currentPageViewController.index
          let newVC = SinglePageViewController()
          newVC.index = currentIndex - 1
          return newVC
        }
        return nil
      }
```

This approach works and the startup time is great - however, the swiping has now become sluggish and not smooth at all.

Can any one advise on how this issue can be resolved?

Comment: You could possibly try setting it up in a way that once your application reaches a certain point (in amount of view controllers), it starts recycling old view controllers to display the notes of future weeks.

Comment: Instead of initializing the view controller when you swipe, you should initialize a couple in each direction instead of just the one they're going to next.

Comment: @twist295, do you have an example of this?

Comment: @pbush25, I've been thinking about this as well. But where should the be done? - if I create 3 new view controller in "viewControllerBeforeViewController" i suspect the swiping being even more sluggish

Comment: I don't have an example I was just brainstorming, sorry. Another option would be to put your initial creation of all the view controllers in an operation queue and have the system handle that all on a background thread which would probably allow your app to open faster. However, this approach or your original approach are prone to consume huge amounts of memory as the weeks go on. Up to 52 view controllers is a lot. The other option that I mentioned is probably a better solution.

Comment: I was also just brainstorming, so I don't have an example as well. I'll do some research and post an answer if I figure it out, but it would definitely involve some conditional checking on the pageViewController's viewControllers property (i.e., if pageViewController.viewControllers.count > x {/*handle recycling here*/}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method (creation on demand) is the correct way to do it. If the swipping gets slow then because you spend to much CPU time in init(), viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, etc... Look at the initialization and move every CPU intensive task to background threads.

If you depend on data to create the ViewController then you have to preload the data in advance. But it is not needed to preload the data for more then 2 or 3 of them. If it takes to much time and you still run into performane problems then you have to accept that the device is not fast enough for your requirements and you have to present the user an loading indicator. (like UIActivityIndicator)

If you need help in optimizing the initialization then post your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with using too many UIScrollViews inside a UIScrollView. My solution was to monitor where the user was looking, by using the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method, hooked up to my container scrollview, and populate/remove view according to the direction of the user's scroll.

The direction you can get from `let direction = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(scrollView.superview!)` within the `scrollViewDidScroll` method.

Would this type of method work for you? I could give you more of my code if you'd like!